# Accessing Rails images by direct path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I am integrating a Angular app with Rails and I have a problem with accessing the images. Angular app has a lots of path to images with structure: (for example)

```
   src="assets/img/layout/ico-przystawki.png"
```

But that doesn't work in a Rails application, because I shouldn't be using the 'img' part. It should be like this:

```
   src="assets/layout/ico-przystawki.png"
```

Is there a way to tell Rails application to use direct paths to images, so that I don't have to change every time these paths?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#changing-the-assets-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself using the non-stupid-digest-assets gem for this very purpose. See https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets

Comment: That's not 100% what I was looking for, but that also helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Stop assets precompile and then you can access all img (and assets file) with src="assets/ut/ico-przystawki.png"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the provided rails helper method image_tag instead when you call an image:

```
<div>
   <%= image_tag("ico-przystawki.png") %>
</div>
```

Read more about that here:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag